# mysql table ordering incorrect with group by and order by

Tags: mysql

```
table 1: forum_threads
+-----+------+-------+
| id  | title| status| 
+-----+------+-------+
| 1   |  a   |    1  | 
| 2   |  b   |    1  |
| 3   |  c   |    1  |
| 4   |  d   |    1  |
| 5   |  e   |    1  |
| 6   |  f   |    1  |
+-----+------+-------+

table 2: forum_comments
+-----+----------+--------------------+
| id  | thread_id|         comment    |          
+-----+----------+--------------------+
| 1   |    4     |   hai              | 
| 2   |    4     |   hello            | 
| 3   |    2     |   welcome          | 
| 4   |    2     |   whats your name  | 
| 5   |    6     |   how are you      |
| 6   |    5     |   how old are you  | 
| 7   |    5     |   good             |  
+-----+----------+--------------------+
```

wanted output

```
+-----------+----------+-----------------+
| thread_id | title    |  comment_count  |          
+-----------+----------+-----------------+
|    5      |    e     |       2         |
|    6      |    f     |       1         |
|    2      |    b     |       2         | 
|    4      |    d     |       2         |   
+-----------+----------+-----------------+
```

**my Query**

```
SELECT forum_threads.*,forum_comments.*,count(forum_comments.id) as comment_count 
FROM forum_comments
LEFT JOIN forum_threads ON forum_comments.thread_id = forum_threads.id 
GROUP BY forum_threads.id 
ORDER BY forum_comments.id desc
```

Here I am trying to get the titles by the latest comment.
when I give ORDER BY forum_comments.id this returns the wrong order.
I need to order by the latest comments in the forum_comments table.
this query returns the wrong order please help me to find out the correct order.
how could I solve this easily?

Comment: and what output are you getting?

Comment: @Furquan getting thread_id in descending order not comment id

Comment: Your query gives the results in the order you show in the question.  What's the problem here?  DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/167118/1

Comment: please print forum_comments.id as a column in the result table, and then try to add order by as you did.

Comment: @RocketHazmat here its shows comment id 6 is the last comment but 7 is the last comment in our table

Comment: @Muhammedshanid Can you update the question to show _exactly_ what output you are expecting versus the one you are getting?  Your "wanted output" is what you are getting from the query.

Comment: @RocketHazmat  need the latest comments of each thread

Comment: @Muhammedshanid Are you looking for something like `MAX(forum_comments.id) as latest_comment`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes

Comment: @RocketHazmat  see now i changed query as per your request but still comments are not showing correct http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/167118/8

Comment: @Muhammedshanid OH!  You are trying to get the _value_ (_text_) of the latest comment!  That was not very clear.

Comment: @RocketHazmat got it, thanks

Comment: @Muhammedshanid Is that actually what you are trying to do?  Are you trying to get the _actual_ comment?  Do you want the text of the latest comment, or just its id?  Can you try to update the question to clarify _exactly_ what output you are expecting?  The "wanted output" in your question is what you currently have, so your question is a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you the expected result:

```
select  t2.thread_id, t1.title, t2.comment_count from forum_threads as t1,
(SELECT id, thread_id, count(comment) as comment_count from forum_comments group by thread_id) as t2
where t1.id = t2.thread_id order by t2.id desc;
```

Comment: Is a subquery really needed here?  This same result could be done with a "normal" join (like OP already has).  I'd only use a subquery if you wanted the actual comment text for the latest comment.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using forum_threads.* and forum_comments.* can you give specific column names and try.

If that doesn't work you should try explicitly assigning primary and foreign keys.